# Compare File.GetCreationTime with datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, compareto

I'm new to C#, so forgive me.
I'm trying to compare a file creation time with a particular date/time.

ie - file test.text created on date 25/6/2018 10:21:23, if it does then match, else not match.

```
 DateTime comparedate = new DateTime(2018, 6, 25, 10, 21, 23);

 if (File.GetCreationTime("test.txt").CompareTo(comparedate))
 {
 console.writeline("match");
 }
 else
 {
 console.writeline("no match");
 }
```

I know am i going about this completely wrong. Is there a better way to compare file creation times with a specific date/time.
thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `Equals` but note that they most likely will *never* match exactly since the DateTime object stores info down to the tick (1 ten millionth of a second) and your file date would have to be 0ms, 0ns exactly to match. You'd probably have to test each date component separately... `fileDate.Date==comparedate.Date && fileDate.Hour == comparedate.Hour &&` etc..

Comment: Also `CompareTo` returns three classes of values. 0, positive, and negative . To test for a match using `CompareTo`, you'd compare the result with zero. `if (File.GetCreationTime("test.txt").CompareTo(comparedate) == 0) { /* equal */ }` but as my comment above states, this will compare down to the tick so an exact match is unlikely in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks man! much appreciated, that did the trick! now i have a better understanding i'll attempt to play with more parts of the DateTime objects as you suggested. Thank you again for taking the time.

Comment: The resolution of the time stamp is 0.1 microseconds.  Not something you can see from Explorer.  So the odds that you get an *exact* match are so low that it is not worth trying.  You have to check for range.